# Intellij idea subversion checkout error: `Cannot run program "svn"`

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I am using intellij idea 13.0. When I am trying to checkout from subversion I am getting error

```
Cannot load supported formats: Cannot run program "svn": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 282):

I solved this by uncheking the "Use command-line client" option from Subversion settings.

This works with version 1.6 and 1.7 only. See @Vic's answer for SVN version 1.8.

Comment: That error is because you need to install a svn client. It tries to run the command using the terminal instead of his internal client by default. It solves my problem, thanks.

Comment: that setting no longer exists

Answer (score 83):

Check my solution, It will work.

Solutions:

First Download Subversion 1.8.13 ( 1.8 )
Download link ( https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/  )

[image]

Then unzipped in a folder. There will have one folder "bin".

Then

Go to settings - > Version control -> Subversion

Copy the url of your downloaded svn.exe that is in bin folder that you have downloaded.

follow the pic:

[image]

Don't forget to give the end name like svn.exe last as per image.

Apply -> Ok

Restart your android studio now.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I am getting following error: 
"No versioned directories to update was found"

Answer (score 37):

If you're using IntelliJ 13 with SVN 1.8, you have to install SVN command line client. Please see more information [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/12/subversion-1-8-and-intellij-idea-13/):

> Unlike its earlier versions, Subversion 1.8 support uses the native command line client instead of SVNKit to run commands. This approach is more flexible and makes the support of upcoming versions much easier.
>   Now, IntelliJ IDEA offers different integration options for each specific Subversion:
>
> 1.6 – SVNKit only
>
> 1.7 – SVNKit and command line client
>
> 1.8 – Command line client only

Comment: Installing svn command line client is the right answer here. Note that on windows default selections for installation of TortoisSVN do not include the command line client.

Answer (score 19):

Disabling **`Use command-line client`** from the settings worked well form me on IntelliJ Ultimate 14.0.

Answer (score 11):

In IntelliJ Idea 2017.1 you can use the embedded SVN client that sadly is not enabled by default. Here's how you can activate it.

1) Open IntelliJ Idea

2) Menu `Help` > `Find Actions...`

[image]

3) Type `subversion` to gain access to the subversion related settings. Choose the item `Subversion Settings` as highlighted in the following picture.

[image]

4) Finally, be sure to uncheck the option `Use command line client`.

[image]

From now on, in the current project, you'll use the embedded subversion.

Comment: that setting no longer exists

Answer (score 9):

Under settings ->verison control -> Subversion, uncheck use command line client. It will work.

Comment: that setting no longer exists

Answer (score 8):

Basically, what IntelliJ needs is svn.exe. You will need to install [Subversion for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/). It automatically adds svn.exe to PATH environment variable. After installing, please restart IntelliJ.

*Note - Tortoise SVN doesn't install svn.exe, at least I couldn't find it in my TortoiseSVN bin directory.*

Comment: Tortoise SVN default installation does not install command line tools. Once you reinstall and check the command line tools, it will install a bin folder with svn.exe. Then in Intellij settings -> subversion give the path to this svn.exe.

Comment: Update 2020: I just installed Tortoise and there was a checkbox in the installer (initially unchecked) to install Command Line Tools. Check that and you're good to go

Answer (score 2):

Seems related to this issue [IDEA-117518](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117518)

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ needs the subversion command(svn) added into Subversion settings.
Here are the steps:
1. Download and Install subversion.
2. check on the command line prompt on windows(cmd) for the same command - svn.

[image]

3. Validate svn command added to File --> settings --> Version Control --> subversion
   [image]
4. Exit IntelliJ studio and relaunch

Answer (score 1):

Fix of this problem is add SVN directory(C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin) to Path system property

Answer (score 1):

For me, on Debian GNU / Linux, installing the subversion package was the solution

```
# aptitude install subversion subversion-tool
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Use command-line client from the settings on IntelliJ Ultimate 14.0.3 works for me.

I checked IDEA's document, IDEA don't need a SVN client software anymore. see below description from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-subversion-integration.html

=================================================================

Prerequisites

IntelliJ IDEA comes bundled with Subversion plugin. This plugin is turned on by default. If it is not, make sure that the plugin is enabled.
**IntelliJ IDEA's Subversion integration does not require a standalone Subversion** client. All you need is an account in your Subversion repository.
Subversion integration is enabled for the current project root or directory.

==================================================================

Answer (score 0):

If you're going with Manoj's solution  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29509007/2024713) and still having the problem try switching off "Enable interactive mode" if available in your version of IntelliJ.
It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are still stuck with errors like this one on Windows or you have one of the following errors :

- Cannot run program "svn"
- No appropriate protocol
- Cannot run 'C:\Program'

Execute the following steps.

- Install your SVN client with command lines tools (probably already done if you are reading this).
- Add your SVN client *bin* directory (which contains the executable *svn.exe*) to the path of your **SYSTEM** environment variables.

Then in IntelliJ, go to *Settings* -> *Version Control* -> *Subversion* and do the following :

- *Path to Subversion executable* : svn (since you added it to your **SYSTEM** path you don't have to put the full path to your executable, moreover if you do this it will produce the error #3 mentioned above).
- *Enable interactive mode* : checked.
- *Network* -> *Use IDEA general proxy settings as default for Subversion* : checked.

Hope this answer will save time for some users.