# Error "can't use subversion command line client : svn" when opening android project checked out from svn

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm new to Android development and the development tools around it. I have checked out a project from svn using TortoiseSVN client (can't manage to do it from within Android Studio), then get this error message after importing the project to Android Studio:

> **can't use subversion command line client : svn**
>
> Probably the path to Subversion executable is wrong. [Fix it..](http://dummylink.com)

When I click "Fix it" link, this dialog pops up:

[image]

But I still have no idea what I am supposed to do to fix this? Any kind of help/suggestion/direction to fix the problem are welcome.

Comment: I couldn't find `svn.exe` as well. Searched in installation folder of TortoiseSVN, Android Studio, entire program files including program files (x86) but to no avail. Any idea?

Comment: The installer of TSVN has an option to include the command line tools. It seems it's off by default. Try to rerun the installer and look for this option. See this related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912169/where-is-svn-exe-for-tortoisesvn

Comment: Dear @TortoiseSVN, please make svn.exe included by default, not sure why it has to be off, absolute no good reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Android Studio cannot find the `svn` command because it's not on `PATH`, and it doesn't know where `svn` is installed.

One way to fix is to edit the `PATH` environment variable: add the directory that contains `svn.exe`. You will need to restart Android Studio to make it re-read the `PATH` variable.

Another way is to set the absolute path of `svn.exe` in the **Use command client box** in the settings screen that you included in your post.

**UPDATE**

According to [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912169/where-is-svn-exe-for-tortoisesvn), TortoiseSVN doesn't include the command line tools by default. But you can re-run the installer and enable it. That will add `svn.exe` to `PATH`, and Android Studio will correctly pick it up.

Comment: Reinstall TSVN checking option to include the command line tools fixed the problem. The installer automatically adds directory where `svn.exe` located to environment variable, which in the end fix the error Android Studio was complaining. Perfect solution!! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Mayur : I have the same issue on macbook. Did you resolve it ?

Comment: i could not find svn.exe in Tortoize svn.

Comment: I'm using Webstorm 11  and not Android, so I had to manually add the path to the settings, but this fixed it!

Answer (score 72):

This is annoying, I wish IntelliJ would handle this better than a startup nag..

If you are using TortoiseSVN 1.8+ on Windows, do this:

1. Run the the **TortoiseSVN Installer**. (It may still be in your Downloads folder)
2. Select the option to `Modify`.
3. Install **Command line client tools** on to the local harddrive.
4. Add `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin` to your `Path` environment variable.
5. Restart IntelliJ.

Answer (score 32):

Saw your problems.

**Solutions:**

**First** Download Subversion *1.8.13 ( 1.8 )* client
Download link (https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html)
at the time of this post the android studio version is less than *1.4*
in my case **1.3.2** so you must avoid the issues here [subversion command line client version is too old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062819/subversion-command-line-client-version-is-too-old-error-in-android-studio) so just download the **1.8** preferably.

[image]

Then **unzipped** in a folder. There will have one folder "**bin**".

Then

**Go** to `settings - > Version control -> Subversion`

**Copy** the url of your downloaded **svn.exe** that is in bin folder that you have downloaded.

follow the picture:

[image]

Don't forget to give the end name like **svn.exe** last as per image.

`Apply -> Ok`

**Restart** your android studio now.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Its a best solution for windows,I've ever seen.

Comment: This option is not in android studio 3.2?

Answer (score 23):

First install [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html). During installation follow this steps

1.Run the the TortoiseSVN Installer.

2.If you have already installed **svn**, "Select the option to Modify".

3.select the **check box** "Install Command line client tools on to the local harddrive".
[image]

4.Add C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin to your Path environment variable or press CTRL+ALT+S in android studio. Then go to "Version Control"-> Subversion -> General -> Check the Checkbox "use commmand line client" and set the path to **C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe**

5.Restart IntelliJ.

```
In Android studio1.5 version when you try to add the file in your project,
android studio will ask for a pop like "schedule for Addition"
to subversion?. select the check box (Remember, don't ask again) and click "yes". 
After this whatever the file you add or remove to your project it will automatically
synced to your svn repository. suppose if you didn't get that dialog, but you want to
add the newly added .png or xml file to svn means you can manually select those files 
which you have added (the newly added file will be in red color) right click 
on that file -> subversion -> Add to VCS or simply select the file and use (CTRL+ALT+A).
```

In the image green color(logo_actionbar) represents to file was already added to svn, red represents yet to add in svn. cool..!

If you want to change the "Schedule for Addition" setting means, Go to **Settings** -> **Version Control** -> **Confirmation** -> **When files are created**
Choose **Show options before adding to version control**

[image]
[image]

Comment: One of the best and simple solution.

Answer (score 12):

I use the IDE Phpstorm,but I think it maybe the same as AS.

1.You should reinstall the svn. And choose option **modify**.
[image]

And next step,you can see the **command line client tools**.

Let's choose first one: **Will be installed on local hard drive**.
[image]

2.Now restart you computer.

Go to the svn location，all the time it will be **C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin**.

If you see the `svn.exe` in C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin,it proved that we reinstall command line client successfully.
Copy `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe` into the IDE.

[image]

3.Restart you IDE.It is ok!

Comment: I seriously think that the fact I didn't have "svn.exe"  at the end of the path "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin" is a bug.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using ubuntu, check weather subversion is installed or not.

If not then install through command line as

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

and check following configurations are selected

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed the issue after upgrading existing svn client on mac OS X with following link:(1.7.x to 1.9.x)

https://ahmadawais.com/installing-svn-subversion-on-yosemite-after-removing-the-old-version/

1. Open Android Studio
2. Go to Settings -> Version Control -> Subversion -> General -> User command line client ( Marked checkbox)

replace ‘svn’ with your svn installed path like ‘/usr/local/bin/svn’

Answer (score 4):

While installation of **[Tortoise SVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)**.

Just change the command line svn tool setting.

Step 1: Click on **command line client tools**

[image]

Step 2: Select first option **(Will be installed on local hard drive)**

[image]

Thats it. Happy Journey.

*[**N.B:** Images are copied from others solution]*

Answer (score 2):

i have fixed the issue by just downloading the android command line tool
from  https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/
download apache comand line tool
unzip it on drive
go to your android settings/version control/subversion
and make sure only command line option is enable
set the path of svn.exe as shown below
C:\Users\viratsinh.parmar\Apace SVN client\Apache-Subversion-1.8.13\bin\svn.exe

now in your android studio update the project , you will be able to commit now.
you can contact me on parmarvirat@yahoo.com

Answer (score 2):

i was also getting the same Error, if you are using TortoiseSVN-1.9.5 just do two step Process
1:Click on TSVN.exe tool and
2:Select there on Second Window the Command line for Save on Local Drive with giving the path
3:Click ok
Now Restart You Android Studio/IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

There are better answers here, but how I fix this may be relevant for someone:

After checking out the project from SVN, instead of choosing the **1.7** version, I chose **Subversion 1.6** and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Installing [Subversion for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/) should solve the issue.
Please see my answer here  -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31627732/3433133

Answer (score 1):

If you using windows, you can fix it via install SVN Tool.
If you using Linux/MacOS, you can fix it via install subversion.
After that, just select using svn command.
Your problems is resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, got same problem after Android Studio update (and several months without using it...).

I solved it by running the following command in a console:

```
mv .subversion/ .subversion.bak
```

I prefer that command to `rm -R .subversion` since it left me a rollback option.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo apt install subversion
```

Answer (score 0):

I have switched to GIT long ago.
However, when migrating to Android Studio Giraffe, I suddenly got that SVN error :

> can't use subversion command line client : svn

Even worse, my GIT integration did not work anymore, I could not commit any files to GIT anymore.

Then I found out that there was still an SVN reference in `.idea\vcs.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="VcsDirectoryMappings">
    <mapping directory="" vcs="svn" />
    <mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$/../.." vcs="Git" />
  </component>
</project>
```

By simply removing the file with `vcs="svn"`, everything worked again.