# TortoiseSVN and IDEAIntelliJ local repository - Setup Questions

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, tortoisesvn

I created a local repository with TortoiseSVN. I added my code folder.
Now I am trying to do a Version Control Checkout with IntelliJ 13.
But what is the URL for a local repository?

I've only used Tortoise together with Visual Studio and there you can integrate TortoiseSVN directly. In IntelliJ you have to use Subversion, right?

Comment: For example file:///C:/SvnRepo

Comment: That's what I tried. But I always get: "svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL"

Comment: I just tried it and it works.

Comment: :( do I need a svn server as well or is tortoiseSvn enough?

Comment: tortoiseSvn is enough, but do you have a right version?

Comment: I use the latest TortoiseSVN and Intellij Version.
TortoiseSVN 1.8.7, Build 25475 - 64 Bit , 2014/05/05 20:52:12
Subversion 1.8.9, -release. IntelliJ 13.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this helped me to fix it! Tortoise doesn't install the command line tools by default. You need to rerun the setup and install them.

[Error "can't use subversion command line client : svn" when opening android project checked out from svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572861/error-cant-use-subversion-command-line-client-svn-when-opening-android-proj)