# "Subversion command line client version is too old" error in Android Studio

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, tortoisesvn

Whenever I open a project in Android Studio, I'll see this error:

[image: Error]

When I click "Fix it", it will show this window:

[image: Fix it]

I don't know what to do because **I'm running TortoiseSVN 1.9.0**, which is the **latest version**.

What should I do to fix this error? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's just misprint: must be "too new"

Android Studio based on Intellij IDEA, [Intellij 14.1.4 cannot use svn 1.9.0](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140754)

Comment: After downgrading TortoiseSVN to 1.8, the error disappeared. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Forte_201092 Can you please share the path where u downloaded 1.8 version

Comment: @Aada https://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/changes I use Android Studio 1.3.1 and downloaded Version 5.0.2. It works well now. :)

Comment: @Aada: Here is the path to download TortoiseSVN 1.8: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.8.12/Application/

Answer (score 5):

Intellij IDEA 14 works with SVN 1.9, it just shows a warning: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140754

Answer (score 2):

Svn 1.9 command line client should work in IDEA - just warning (you can close it) is shown.
upgrade new version  14.1.5 from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14.1+EAP or 15 EAP: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+15+EAP .

https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/471975

Comment: Yet Android Studio will be stuck on a perpetual "Refreshing VCS history" task until you stop it manually.

Comment: We've had the same problem as mentioned by @A.Grandt . Using Intellij 15 with Tortoise 1.9, Intellij gets stuck "Refreshing VCS history"

Answer (score 2):

As [Lazy Badger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32063047/2823516) says, it should say `is too new`.
Faced same problem on Debian. I had 1.9 version installed. I fixed it by removing my installed version and then installing 1.8 version:

```
aptitude remove subversion
aptitude install subversion=1.8.10-6+deb8u1
```

**EDIT**
As I understand, the devs of Android Studio have fixed this issue in latest releases.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related with broken path:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Issue was resolved after installing xcode-select:
`xcode-select --install`

Comment: Here is a topic about it: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-sierra-invalid-active-developer-path