# Can't use Subversion command line client

Tags: intellij-idea, tortoisesvn

I am using intelliJ 14.1.4 on Windows 7, downloaded the latest tortoise svn client 1.9.0.After I configuring the SVN path ,
IntelliJ throws an error :  Can't use Subversion command line client: C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe
            Subversion command line client version is too old (1.9.0).

what is the version I supposed to use?

Comment: Slik-SVN 1.8x worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062819/subversion-command-line-client-version-is-too-old-error-in-android-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- IntelliJ 14.1.5 or 15 with SVN 1.9
- IntelliJ 14.1.4 with SVN 1.8

Comment: I have the same issue out of the blue with 14.1.4 +  SVN 1.8

Answer (score 0):

write  just  svn on  path to  Subvrsion  executable