# How to integrate svn and intellij idea

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Before I always used git. And integration with idea was excellent.

My new project used svn as cvs.
I want to integrate this with idea.

My actions:

I have downloaded `tortoise svn` and using this tool I has checkouted the project. tortoise asked login and password before.

I have opened project in idea. and I seee error:

[image: http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0005/3037/338909/151124/3d67a80b77.jpg]

when I click to fixx this issue I see following menu:

[image]

As I understand I should type login and password somewhere. I have not ideas where. Please clarify my misunderstanding.

Comment: This may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572861/error-cant-use-subversion-command-line-client-svn-when-opening-android-proj

Answer (score 1):

According to your settings, You set your command line client as `svn`. It makes you must add `svn` to `PATH` before you can use idea's svn correctly. So please make sure `svn` has been added to `PATH`.

To edit `PATH`, here is a reference:
[How To Add/Edit Environment Variables in Windows 7](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/). It's totally same in Windows 10 and Windows 8.1.

Also you can specify the absolute path of `svn.exe` in your settings, like `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn`. I think this can works.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: It became working after installing console client(repair tortoise svn).