# How to install Tortoise SVN in to Android Studio 2.1 Latest Version

Tags: android, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have downloaded 64bit Tortoise SVN and installed in C Drive in to my system. I have created seperate folder for SVN client and branch,tags,trunk folders and paste the code and commit in to that SVN server. 
Studio :
next, I tried to set tortoise svn path in to studio Version Control-Subversion-user command line client: path url.. But, I could not find svn.exe in to this path C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin. Anyway, I could not set path into studio.

Exactly dont know, where made mistake ?

I followed these sites:
[Error "can't use subversion command line client : svn" when opening android project checked out from svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572861/error-cant-use-subversion-command-line-client-svn-when-opening-android-proj)
http://www.programering.com/a/MDO1czMwATU.html

Last one is for Apache Subversion command line tools :
https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/
using this Apache SVN, we can able to download svn.exe and set it into path and can able to access the source code download and access the apache svn in to studio.
But, I want Tortoise SVN only to access in to Studio

Comment: I referred this to first tome commit the code successfully.:http://blogs.wandisco.com/2011/10/17/how-to-install-tortoisesvn-and-make-your-first-repository-change/.  But,  I struggled for , set svn.exe path in to studio. I could not find svn.exe in Tortoise installed software 1.9.4 latest https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You do not "install TortoiseSVN into Android Studio", you just tell the IDE where `svn.exe` command-line client is. That's why you should specify the full path to the executable.

Up-to-date TortoiseSVN versions provide svn.exe client and its path has to be `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin`. Check whether you have the command-line tools by modifying your TortoiseSVN client installation:

1. Go to **Programs and Features**.
2. Select **TortoiseSVN** and chose the **Modify** command.
3. Follow the wizard's steps and make sure that you have *command line client tools* selected.
4. Under **Command line client tools** - click and select drop down menu item below
   for - Entire feature will be installed on local hard drive.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I installed TortoiseSVN. But, I could not find svn.exe in this path C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin.. thats my problem. any mistake while installing TortoiseSVN in to my system.

Comment: @harikrishnan: Then you only have a minimal installation, not a full installation of TortoiseSVN.

Comment: sure.. let me check my installation again..thank you

Comment: thank you.your answer is correct. i just added some minor steps for installation, you may accepts my edit.

Comment: thank for your answer. I enabled 'Command line client tools' , when modify wizard. and DONE.

Answer (score 4):

This may also simple steps to understand the to install the tortoise svn into studio latest version

step:1

- Download Tortoise SVN latest version and install in to C drive
- make sure that you have "-Command line client tools selected"
- Under Command line client tools - click and select drop down menu item below
  for - Entire feature will be installed on local hard drive.

step:2

- Install Default SVN & REPOSITORY & VCS GRAPH plug in to Studio..
- File - Settings - Plugins--> Select Browse repository
- then, search SVN
- then, select SVN Revision Graph - Install it
- then, SVNToolBox - Install it.
- then, VCS Watch - Install it.

VCS watch is a plugin that periodically checks for any changes in the current project's repositories.

- File - Settings - Version Control- Subversion - General- Use command line client: "select the Tortoise svn path from drive"
  ex: C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe

-Apply-Ok.