# How to commit the Tortoise SVN code at very first time in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, tortoisesvn

I have created the trunk, branch, tag folder one by one. Also I have checkout the empty URL `.svn` file into trunk folder inside. Its not coming properly.

Answer (score 2):

I found the steps to commit the studio code into Tortoise SVN Server:

Very First Time Commit the code in to SVN Repository:

Create Seperate SVN folder at any drive -

- Inside Create branches,tags,trunk folders one by one seperately
- Inside trunk, pls checkout with empty URL FIRST.
- then, copy your very first time source code and paste it here.
- build - need to add this folder in to Ignore list.
- then, right click and select svn commit -  select all and enter your message and give ok..

Reference Link:

http://blogs.wandisco.com/2011/10/17/how-to-install-tortoisesvn-and-make-your-first-repository-change/

[Error "can't use subversion command line client : svn" when opening android project checked out from svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572861/error-cant-use-subversion-command-line-client-svn-when-opening-android-proj)

[How to install Tortoise SVN in to Android Studio 2.1 Latest Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430534/how-to-install-tortoise-svn-in-to-android-studio-2-1-latest-version/38434057#38434057)

https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-and-TortoiseSVN-and-Make-Your-First-Repository-Change

http://www.programering.com/a/MDO1czMwATU.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am not using svn plugin in android studio, and doing it manually as you said. I was getting problems for build directory but now I have added it in ignore list. And this is working perfect

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is instead of using SVN plugin for android, do it manually because:

1. Svn plugin will make studio load slower and degrade your pc performance
2. If multiple people are working on same project then more chances of conflicts will arise. When you do it manually, you always have a backup copy available.

You can do it by using some GUI based SVN System like TortoiseSVN as below:

1. First, You will need SVN software installed on your computer and have an SVN repository configured.
2. Then you will checkout the project from your server. This will create a new folder called “projectname” on your computer and download the project from your server (at this point it is most likely an empty folder).List item
3. Now you can then copy or create your android project in this directory
4. When you are happy with your changes you can commit your changes to the svn to create a new version
   (Please include messages with each commit.)

The source of above information is [here](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/02/android-using-svn-with-your-apps-project-and-eclipse/comment-page-1/#comment-124036). Check it for more details.

I use TortoiseSvn [TortoiseSVN](https://tortoisesvn.net/) on my windows machine for android projects.