# PyCharm + TortoiseSVN giving password issue

Tags: svn, version-control, pycharm, tortoisesvn

My company uses TortoiseSVN for version control. I am trying to integrate it into PyCharm v18.2.

Step 1 was to directly download the svn.exe file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31627732/2379009)) as it does not come by default w/ TortoiseSVN. This gets rid of the `Cannot run program “svn”` error.

Now however, when I want to commit, PyCharm asks me for my SVN credentials (
UN/password). The repo I want to access is local and made by me. I never set up credentials in TortoiseSVN. How do I get around this to be able to see history/commit/etc...

Thanks!

Comment: When you say local repository does it mean local as in `file:///C:/PathToLocalRepository` or local as in `http:\\localserver\repopath`?

Comment: @SiddharthKaul the former: file:///C:/PathToLocalRepository